# incorrect redirect from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, http-redirect

trying to go https, but when I use the following in my `.htaccess` I get redirect problem error

here is what I have in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

 #Uncomment lines below when uploading to the live server
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L,NC]

 #Uncomment lines below when uploading to the live server
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|tif|js|css|xls|xlsx|zip|rar|pdf|ods|ots)$ - [F]
```

Please help

Comment: If you can, please consider your approach to defining redirects, if you can avoid using .htaccess, and define most of it in virtualhsot even better. Most times a redirect to ssl involves defining the appropiate virtualhosts and and a simple Redirect / https://hostname/, the request_filename checks to then go to index.php, can all be removed for a single Fallbackresource directive, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule has many erroneous `[OR]` conditions and that is causing redirect loop.

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

And test after clearing your browser cache.